# Praying left-out prayers before becoming a Muslim

Tags: salat, sawm, salat-qada

As-salam-alaikum Bismillah !

I am a new Muslim and I am now going to be of 18 age this year inshallah. My question is before becoming Muslim I was a disbeliever, so I want to make up the prayer that I left when I was non-muslim, and not only prayers but even the tasbeeh and fasting.

Can I do so?  From which age prayer is obilgatory upon a boy.  Is it 12 or 13? That means I need to make up for 5 or 6 years of missed prayers.

Please give any proof from any hadith which says it is permissible. I want Allah to love me :)..

Please answer as fast as possible as i am going to fast tomorrow and also tell me what should the intention be while making up those prayer and fasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't have to pray the Salah from when you were not a muslim. This can be seen because neither did the Prophet (SAW) nor did any of the Sahaba.

Furthermore a person is forgiven for everything he did before if he accepts Islam:

> When Allah instilled the love for Islam in my heart, I (Amr ibn Al-Aas) went to Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and said, 'Extend your right hand, so that I pledge allegiance to you.' He (ﷺ) stretched out his right hand, but I withdrew my hand. He said, 'What is the matter, 'Amr?' I said, 'I wish to lay down same conditions.' He asked, 'What conditions do you wish to put forward?' I replied, 'To be granted forgiveness.' He said, '**Do you not know that (embracing) Islam wipes out all that has gone before it (previous misdeeds)**? (Muslim)

So, You don't need to make up for Salah before your Islam. All that you did (or didn't do) is forgiven. Now, you should just look to the present and future. Don't forget your Salaat, now.

> Say (O Muhammad SAW to mankind): "If you (really) love Allah then follow me (i.e. accept Islamic Monotheism, follow the Quran and the Sunnah), Allah will love you and forgive you of your sins. And Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful." (3:31)

As long as you are Muslim and follow Allah's commands, InshaAllah, Allah already loves you.

Answer (score 3):

Allah says in the Qur'an:

> Indeed, prayer has been decreed upon the believers a decree of specified times. ([4:103](http://legacy.quran.com/4/103))

One could use this verse as an evidence that only a believer is asked to perform the prayer on time. But I think I would get some objections.

Note that this verse also says that once you convert your old register of misdeeds is white (clear):

> Say to those who have disbelieved [that] **if they cease, what has previously occurred will be forgiven for them**. But if they return [to hostility] - then the precedent of the former [rebellious] peoples has already taken place. ([8:38](http://legacy.quran.com/8/38))

This means your new life with a new register started the day you embraced Islam and that's the moment you were ordered to pray to Allah! Not any moment or time before this.
You may find many other similar verses.

The moment you believed you should stay away from any misdeed and any kufr/shirk from your early live to lead a happy life:

> - Indeed, those who have said, "Our Lord is Allah " and then remained on a right course - the angels will descend upon them, [saying], "Do not fear and do not grieve but receive good tidings of Paradise, which you were promised. ([41:30](http://legacy.quran.com/41/30))
> - Indeed, those who have said, "Our Lord is Allah ," and then remained on a right course - there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve. ([46:13](http://legacy.quran.com/46/13))

This can also be found as the most important advice in the sunnah (here a short version from a longer hadith):

> I said, "O Messenger of Allah, tell me something about al-Islam which I can ask of no one but you." He (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, "Say I believe in Allah — and then be steadfast." ([40 Hadiths of imam an-Nawawi](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/21))

And in the story of the conversion of 'Amr ibn al-'Aas you may read:

> Are you not aware of the fact that Islam wipes out all the previous (misdeeds)? ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/228))